# How many elements of a group can have order 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, how many elements of $G$ can have order 1? I know this is seems like a straightforward question, but it has confused me immensely.

How could I determine the number of elements with order 1 without knowing anything else about the group?

Comment: Doesn't order one mean $a = a^1 = e$.  That would be exactly one, wouldn't it.

Comment: That was my instinct but then I confused myself more I think haha

Comment: *Hint:* how many units exist in a group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x\in G$ has order $1$, then $x=e$. But $e$ must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x\neq y$ are two elements of order $1$ in a group $G$. Then $x=x+y=y$, a contradiction. Then $G$ can only have one element of order $1$ (the identity).